# Bootstrap tooltip with angularjs using $http to load the content of the tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, tooltip

I am running into small issue that I can't seem to figure out. The code below works, except for the first time you hover over the link. Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/LpK6d/1/

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
<a
    class="pop-over"
    data-original-title="default value"
    data-placement="top">test link</a>
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('popOver', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        element.bind('mouseover', function(e) {
            $http.get("http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=someFunction")
              .success(function(data) {
                 attr.$set('originalTitle', data);
                 element.tooltip();                  
              });
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it need to load on each mouseover? Would this work: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsMY4 ?

Comment: @jkoreska It does need to load on every mouseover, because I use the data for the tooltip.

Comment: Ok, you might consider caching it at least. How's this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZsMY4/1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so calling `.tooltip()` before the AJAX call might seem like a good idea, but the method copies the `data-original-title` or `'title'`into its internal variables so we can't change it :(.

the thing is that calling tooltip() it just listens to onmouseover events. You have to call `.tooltip('show')` to make it appear programmatically.

Here is the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rB5zT/49/

This is the correct way to do it:

```
var app =  angular.module("myApp", [])
app.directive('popOver', function($http) {
 return {
  restrict: 'C',
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    var i =0;
    element.tooltip();
    $(element).bind('mouseover',function(e) {

        $http.get("test").success(function(){
           attr.$set('originalTitle', "Some text "+i++);  
            element.tooltip('show');
         });
        });
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: the problem is that first time you hover over the tooltip, it displays default text. My goal was to load the content via xhr every time someone hover over the link.

Comment: OK, here is the way to do it. Might seem like a work-around, but you do have to do a http request to get the actual value of the tooltip. Hope it helps

Comment: This is the working version. You have to call `tooltip('show')` on ajax response :).

Comment: @Shriram, thanks for pointing out the bug. The fiddle URLs for getting  bootstrap js and css were not working anymore. They were redirecting to getboostrap.com.

Comment: Don't forget fixTitle... otherwise it won't work.                $(element).bind('mouseover', function (e) {
                    element.attr('title', element.title).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
                });